# How to modify a value when exporting a Kendo grid to Excel?

Tags: html, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

So, I am trying to look for a way to modify the values an exported to excel the same way you modify a value in a Kendo Grid using `ClientTemplate()`. Currently, the way I am exporting to Excel is through this method:

```
.Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("InvitedList.xlsx")
        .AllPages(true)
        .Filterable(true)
```

I am using `.ClientTemplate()` the following way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<(TableLocation)>()
        .Name("List of Invited")
        .Columns(col => {
            ...Some Columns...
            columns.Bound(p => p.RSVP).Title("Is Attending?").Width(75).ClientTemplate("#if(RSVP == 0){#No#}else{#Yes#}#");
            ...More Columns...
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => {
            toolbar.Excel();
        })
        ...
        .Excel(excel => excel
            .FileName("InvitedList.xlsx")
            .AllPages(true)
            .Filterable(true)
        )
        ...
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            ...
        )
)
```

I haven't found a way here in StackOverflow, and the Telerik Docs seem to have only script solutions, while I am looking for a way to do it from the `@` escape on the cshtml page.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Edit: Added a some more details that hopefully will clear some doubts.

Comment: Which data binding are you using?

Comment: @mmillican believe I am using `gridBinding`.

Comment: Are you using `.Server()` or `.Ajax()` binding for the data source?

Comment: @mmillican I am using `.Ajax()`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at their example (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export) it looks like the `ClientTemplate()` format will be exported to the Excel.

One note though, you referenced using `@` escape - this will not work in ClientTemplates.  You must use their syntax, for example:

```
.ClientTemplate("#=myValue#")
```

Comment: `.ClientTemplate()` Works when I am on the website, (Show 'Attending' or 'Not Attending' instead of a 1 or a 0) but when I export to Excel, the 0 or 1 are shown on the column. Could you be more specific about not using the `@` escape? I am currently using that to make the entire grid, not only for the `.ClientTemplate()` method.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include your entire grid definition?

Comment: I don't think I have permission to add the entire definition, but I will edit it to include more details.